# Excel Workbook populate a date on sheet1 and return the hours of daylight in that day from the table in sheet2

Tags: excel

Excel Workbook `sheet1` calculates a date that populates cell `J7` with the date as `15-AUG-2018`

[image: sheet1C7]

The same Workbook sheet2 contains a table of hours of the day for the entire year.

[image: sheet2]

How can I return the value from the table on `sheet2` for `15-AUG`
to cell `J8` on `sheet1` when `15-AUG-2018` is populated?

But return the hours of the day value for **any date** that is populated in cell `J7`

So if `15-AUG-2018` populates cell `J7` on `sheet1` and `sheet2` the table value of `AUG-15` has `14:18` hours in the day so it would return `14:18` in cell `J8` on `sheet1`

or if

`10-APR-2018` populates cell `J7` on sheet1 then `sheet2` table value of `APR-10` would return to cell `J8` the hours for that day which is `13:24`.

This is a LINK TO THE TABLE
[Hours of Daylight Tables](http://aa.usno.navy.mil/data/docs/Dur_OneYear.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `index` function to get the value from `sheet2` to `sheet1`. Assuming that the data is in cells `b2:m32` on `sheet2`, you can use the following formula is cell `j8` of `sheet1`:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(INDEX(Sheet2!B2:M32,DAY(J7),MONTH(J7))),,INDEX(Sheet2!B2:M32,DAY(J7),MONTH(J7)))
```

This function checks if the corresponding cell is blank in `sheet2` and if it is not, it returns the value from the row (which is the date extracted from the input date in `j7` using `day()` function) and the column (which is the month extracted from the input date in `j7` using the `month()` function)

Comment: Is your cell where you enter your date propperly formatted as a date.

Comment: I have checked again and it is returning `I16` for me. Check your date format to make sure the day and month are correct. Use the formula `=day(j7)` in any cell and you should get `15` and `=month(j7)` should give `8`. If it is so, then the given formula will get the value from the row number corresponding to `day(j7)` and column number corresponding to `month(j7)`.

Comment: I was attempting VLOOKUP and INDEX and MATCH but you solved it. I need to delete my comments. `This is the solution`.I cannot vote it up however.But a big thank you nicely done.